# Matter JS - unable to render SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg, matter.js

I'm using Matter JS and I am trying to render my own SVG shape to a canvas. After following their documentation though I keep running into errors. Here is a working demo I found online:

https://jsfiddle.net/gf3jLvjt/4/

You can see that the path is correctly rendered to the canvas. When I try replacing either just the `<path />` element in the example or the entire `<svg>` I get errors in the console. Here is an example of where i'm using my own SVG but getting errors:

https://jsfiddle.net/gf3jLvjt/6/

My best guess is that this is caused by the format i'm saving out the SVG in but i'm not sure if a) this is correct or b) what settings I could change to fix this.

CHeers

Comment: Fiddle is dead, no [mcve] was put into this question so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253422/how-to-use-a-font-awesome-svg-in-matter-js/65299500#65299500) for an example of using an SVG path as input to MJS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to `Matter.js` but it looks like the problem in your code is that you are not using `Bodies.fromVertices` correctly.

```
 let body = Bodies.fromVertices(100 * i + 300, 200 + i * 30, vertexSets, {
   isStatic: false,
 }, true, 0.01, 30);
```

The documentation is asking for vectors instead of vertices.

`Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(x, y, [[vector]], [options], [flagInternal=false], [removeCollinear=0.01], [minimumArea=10])`]

http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html

This results in `body` (`let body = ...`) being undefined.

I'm not yet sure how to fix your code, unfortunately.