# How to use an SVG image in Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, font-awesome, matter.js

What I'm trying to do:
Use a Font Awesome SVG - [sleigh](https://fontawesome.com/icons/sleigh) -  in matter.js.

I've tried this:

```js
Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(500, 50 , Matter.Svg.pathToVertices("sleigh.svg"))
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><path d="M612.7 350.7l-9.3-7.4c-6.9-5.5-17-4.4-22.5 2.5l-10 12.5c-5.5 6.9-4.4 17 2.5 22.5l9.3 7.4c5.9 4.7 9.2 11.7 9.2 19.2 0 13.6-11 24.6-24.6 24.6H48c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h516c39 0 73.7-29.3 75.9-68.3 1.4-23.8-8.7-46.3-27.2-61zM32 224c0 59.6 40.9 109.2 96 123.5V400h64v-48h192v48h64v-48c53 0 96-43 96-96v-96c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32h-96v64c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64h-20.7c-65.8 0-125.9-37.2-155.3-96-29.4-58.8-89.6-96-155.3-96H32C14.3 32 0 46.3 0 64s14.3 32 32 32v128z"/></svg>
```

But got:

```
matter.js:4624 matter-js: Svg.pathToVertices: SVGPathSeg not defined, a polyfill is required.

matter.js:7554 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfItems' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

(P. S: I'm pretty new to matter.js, so sorry if this is a silly question…)

Comment: Did you check the docs? They have a [working example](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#svg) and mention "To use this module you also need the SVGPathSeg polyfill: https://github.com/progers/pathseg". I don't see a [mcve] of your code here, so it's unclear if you've followed the error message's advice to include this polyfill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting this working can be a bit of a fuss because, as [the docs point out](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Svg.html), there are a couple of external scripts necessary to [polyfill `SVGPathSeg`](https://github.com/progers/pathseg) and to [decompose a 2D polygon into convex pieces](https://github.com/schteppe/poly-decomp.js/). Version frustrations ensue.

The versions that worked for me after referencing [the official example](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/svg.js) and [this outdated Codepen example](https://codepen.io/garethfoote/pen/wzYzNL/?editors=1010) are shown below in the snippet.

Worth noting, the [`Matter.Bodies.fromVertices` docs](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_fromVertices) state: "if the vertices are concave, they will be decomposed if [poly-decomp.js](https://github.com/schteppe/poly-decomp.js) is available. Note that this process is not guaranteed to support complex sets of vertices (e.g. those with holes may fail)" which probably accounts for the extra line you see in the rendered body.

Furthermore, MJS' built-in renderer is mainly for prototyping purposes, so the fact that there's an extra line on the body likely won't matter if you're animating the original SVG element on the page. You may also try the premium font-awesome filled sleighs, but I don't have access to them.

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine
});
const bodies = [
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 210, 810, 60, {isStatic: true}),
  ...[...document.querySelectorAll("svg path")].map(path => {
    const body = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
      100, 80, Matter.Svg.pathToVertices(path), {}, true
    );
    Matter.Body.scale(body, 0.2, 0.2);
    return body;
  })
];
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, bodies);
Matter.Runner.run(engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);
```

```css
svg {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.1/pathseg.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/poly-decomp@0.3.0/build/decomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="sleigh" class="svg-inline--fa fa-sleigh fa-w-20" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M612.7 350.7l-9.3-7.4c-6.9-5.5-17-4.4-22.5 2.5l-10 12.5c-5.5 6.9-4.4 17 2.5 22.5l9.3 7.4c5.9 4.7 9.2 11.7 9.2 19.2 0 13.6-11 24.6-24.6 24.6H48c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h516c39 0 73.7-29.3 75.9-68.3 1.4-23.8-8.7-46.3-27.2-61zM32 224c0 59.6 40.9 109.2 96 123.5V400h64v-48h192v48h64v-48c53 0 96-43 96-96v-96c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32h-96v64c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64h-20.7c-65.8 0-125.9-37.2-155.3-96-29.4-58.8-89.6-96-155.3-96H32C14.3 32 0 46.3 0 64s14.3 32 32 32v128z"></path></svg>
```

To reproduce your error, comment out

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.1/pathseg.js"></script>
```