# How to draw a semicircle with matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am playing with the [matterjs](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/) library, it's awesome!

I am trying to figure out how I can draw a semicircle like these:

[image]

I tried with `Bodies.circle`, `Bodies.rectangle` and `Bodies.polygon` but with no luck.

It seems like a pretty simple shape but I don't know if it is possible to draw a semicirle with the library.

Any recommendation would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SVGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253422/how-to-use-an-svg-image-in-matter-js/65299500) are one approach:

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
});
const bodies = [
  Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
    400, 210, 810, 60, {isStatic: true, angle: 0.0}
  ),
  ...Array(50).fill().map(() => {
    const path = document.querySelector("svg path");
    const body = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
      Math.random() * innerWidth, // x
      0,    // y
      Matter.Svg.pathToVertices(path), // vertexSets
      {},   // options
      true, // flag internal
    );
    const scale = Math.random() / 2 + 0.2;
    Matter.Body.scale(body, scale, scale);
    return body;
  }),
];
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [...bodies, mouseConstraint]);
Matter.Runner.run(engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);
```

```css
svg {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.1/pathseg.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<svg>
  <!-- SVG path from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Semicircle.svg -->
  <path d="M 98,93 L 169,93 C 169,54 137,22 98,22 C 59,22 27,54 27,93 L 98,93 z " />
</svg>
```

Comment: I forgot to add a codepen example, sorry about that.

https://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/eYWpdLp

I was able to do a sort of semicircle with the rectangle shape, and I add your svg code suggestion, more or less they look the same.

do you know why the shape doesn't seem smooth as the svg?

you can easily see the points, so the curve is not very smooth.

is there a way to make the curve more smooth?

I guess that adding more points will make the curve more smooth?

Comment: Yep, that's the general idea, more points on the circle makes it more smooth, but there's likely a performance impact, so it's probably a matter of striking the right balance for your use case. This example is really good, and thanks for sharing -- I recommend editing it into your question for posterity. You can also add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) showing your rectangle technique.