# Notch doesn't get displayed in concave shape in matter.js

Tags: javascript, 2d, physics, matter.js

I need to make this shape in matter.js:

[image]

This is what I tried (I took the points from Figma and inserted them into matter.js):

```
const logoBottom = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
    150,
    150,
    [
        [
            Matter.Vector.create(13.06, 22.53),
            Matter.Vector.create(66.94, 22.53),
            Matter.Vector.create(58.24, 37.54),
            Matter.Vector.create(39.03, 37.54),
            Matter.Vector.create(48.64, 54.1),
            Matter.Vector.create(40, 69),
        ],
    ],
    { isStatic: true }
);
```

However, the notch on the side doesn't get displayed and I don't know why.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with your imports. Did you add the necessary poly-decomp script for concave objects? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65299500/6243352) and these GH issues: [449](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/449), [487](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/487), [15](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/15).

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not importing from an SVG, but I have these Vertices right away. I thought I don't need poly-decomp for that. But i added it and now it works. thank you

Comment: That's right, the SVG goes through an extra stage but ultimately it's plugged into `fromVertices` which needs poly-decomp to deal with concave regions. Feel free to add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) since I can't find a great dupe target, so this might be suitable as a canonical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you missed that poly-decomp needs to be added.

With poly-decomp:

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const runner = Matter.Runner.create();
const render = Matter.Render.create({element: document.body, engine});
const logoBottom = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
  150,
  150,
  [
    [
      Matter.Vector.create(13.06, 22.53),
      Matter.Vector.create(66.94, 22.53),
      Matter.Vector.create(58.24, 37.54),
      Matter.Vector.create(39.03, 37.54),
      Matter.Vector.create(48.64, 54.1),
      Matter.Vector.create(40, 69),
    ],
  ],
  {isStatic: true},
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, logoBottom);
Matter.Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/poly-decomp@0.2.1/build/decomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Without poly-decomp:

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const runner = Matter.Runner.create();
const render = Matter.Render.create({element: document.body, engine});
const logoBottom = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
  150,
  150,
  [
    [
      Matter.Vector.create(13.06, 22.53),
      Matter.Vector.create(66.94, 22.53),
      Matter.Vector.create(58.24, 37.54),
      Matter.Vector.create(39.03, 37.54),
      Matter.Vector.create(48.64, 54.1),
      Matter.Vector.create(40, 69),
    ],
  ],
  {isStatic: true},
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, logoBottom);
Matter.Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what version of MJS you're using, but this gives me the following warning:

> matter-js: Bodies.fromVertices: Install the 'poly-decomp' library and use Common.setDecomp or provide 'decomp' as a global to decompose concave vertices.

Related GH issues: [#449](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/449), [#15](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/15), [#487](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/487).